# android scrollview and scrollbar position

Tags: android

I have a scrollview that contain a linearlayout. I need to give little margin on the right of the scrollbar of my scrollview ,i.e scrollbar should  visible inside the linearlayout not at the border.

```
<ScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scrollbattrack"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbarthumb"

    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ListView"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

          </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with the left and right margin of the LinearLayout inside the scrollview or as said in another post with the left and right padding.

Answer (score 0):

find equivalent for XML:i could do it using code in this way::

```
 ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(Activity);

 LinearLayout.LayoutParams svParams = new
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ht, 0.0F);

 svParams.setMargins(1, 0, 1, 0);
```